# Train sklearn model with different data types. (Float and list of Ints)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I need to train a Decision Tree model using sklearn fit function.
The data is similar to the following one:

```
   min_out  min_in  max_out  max_in    mean_out      mean_in  \
0       86     -76     1085   -1508  238.078512  -525.545276   
2       86     -86      170   -1508  111.454545  -217.470377   
3       86     -86      188   -1508  112.763485  -126.167939   
4       86    -122     1508   -1508  305.945946 -1112.227397   
5       86     -76     1508   -1508  195.330377  -875.092722   

                                            Features  
0  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...  
2  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...  
3  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...  
4  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...  
5  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...
```

What can be seen here is that I'm using 6 attributes with float/int values and 1 with a binary list.
When I try to run the fit function, I get the following error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I understand that the error is due the list of int values, but it's necessary and I cannot do it without that attribute.
An option was to convert the list to string like "010100011100011", but that actually does not work as the model transforms it to a float number and what I need to compare is on which position there are 1s and 0s. This is because each position corresponds to a feature, 1 means feature enabled, 0 means not enabled.
Note: list has always the same size.

Comment: why don't you want to transform this list to columns? so if you have array of N elements you can create N columns, where each column has binary value 0/1. I think it wouldn't be worse than list of binary values (in worst case you can compare or get a baseline).

Comment: @Iskander14yo I will try that and see. Good idea!