# How to train an ML model to predict a diagnosis when given ECG data and its features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I have to train a model to be able to read ecg signal data and extracted features and be able to predict the heart condition of the patient as well as predict if the person is likely to develop one in the future. The database is A large scale 12-lead electrocardiogram database for arrhythmia study on Physionet.

I've started off with running the data through some filters to get rid of the artefacts, and then used the NeuroKit 2.0 feature extraction library to extract features, and then filled in missing data using prediction algorithms. And finally put it all into a dictionary that contains 25 items per patient.

the 25 items are as follows: P,Q,R,S,T peak timestamps (in ms), The onsets of P,R,T waves, the offsets of P,R,T waves, the duration of PR and ST segments, ST, QT, RR, and QRS intervals, and the amplitudes of P,Q,R,S and T peaks, this is followed by the heart rate, and finally the diagnosis

All this data is then converted into a dataframe, which is ultimately converted into a CSV file where the columns are the features, and the number of rows varies per person since the number of peaks per person depends on their heart condition. So each patient has their own CSV file

The problem is, when I try and feed this data to my training model, I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 12, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 11, 9, 12, 9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 23, 12, 10, 13, 11, 9, 9, 13, 9, 12, 10, 15, 17
  y sizes: 12, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 11, 9, 12, 9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 23, 12, 10, 13, 11, 9, 9, 13, 9, 12, 10, 15, 17
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

And I guess I should pad the data, but I feel like it would change my results since the number of peaks is necessary in determining the diagnosis.

The dateset is for 12 leads, but I've taken only a single lead, and patients who have a single diagnosis for simplicity so far.

I thought maybe I could create a single CSV file where each row is for one patient. and each column represents a feature, and each cell has a list of the given values. like

| Patient | P-peaks | Q-Peaks | Etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [554, 1580, 2588, 3636, 4704, 5746, 6804, 7862, 8904] | [692, 1674, 2720, 3768, 4794, 5878, 6936, 7954, 8994] | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |

But I get errors when I input lists as training data. So I don't know what to do

Comment: You mentioned you get errors. What errors? Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned trying to input lists directly into models, which is not typically how models are trained. Models expect matrices (2D arrays) where rows are samples (in this case, patients) and columns are features. Lists for each patient, especially of different lengths, don't fit this mold, which is why you're facing errors. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220705/train-sklearn-model-with-different-data-types-float-and-list-of-ints#comment136134836_77220705) what advice I gave in similar situation.

Furthermore, as I understand, the issue you're facing is due to the irregular number of extracted features (e.g., peaks) per patient. Machine learning models, in general, expect a fixed number of features for every sample. Maybe you should think about some feature engineering like

- Statistical Features (mean, median, min/max, quantiles, counts, etc.)
- Pad Sequences (If retaining the sequence of peaks is crucial, consider padding the sequences to a fixed length, filling with a neutral value or a designated padding value)
- Time Series to Image (You can convert the time series data into a spectrogram or any other time-frequency representation image and then use convolutional neural networks (CNNs) for classification.)

Comment: I guess your third suggestion might be the best course of action. I've been looking for ways to avoid that. Since I have all the info as numerical data.